# Unable to scrape and fetch data from indeed/linkdin

Tags: web-scraping

I've tried with beautifulSoup, when I'm trying to scrape in indeed I'm getting 403 response, and for linkdin I'm getting 200 for 'https://www.linkedin.com' but when I'm trying "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3346082855&f_E=1%2C2&geoId=105214831&keywords=python%20developer&location=Bengaluru%2C%20Karnataka%2C%20India&refresh=true" or "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs" I'm getting 403.
After I've tried with selenium and scrapy but getting responce like not able find the by the className or Id.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}
skill = input('Enter your Skill: ').strip()
place = input('Enter the location: ').strip()

    for page in range(no_of_pages):
        url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=' + skill + \
        '&l=' + place + '&sort=date' +'&start='+ str(page * 10)
        # url = 'https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu&from=searchOnHP&vjk=e32b640bd3363a4d'

         response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
         html = response.text

         soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

         print(response.status_code)
         outer_most_point=soup.find('div',attrs={'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'})
```

Error Message:
Enter your Skill: data analyst
Enter the location: Chennai, Tamil Nadu
Enter the # of pages to scrape: 2
403

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
28         # "UL" lists where the data are stored:
29         print("djgcvhsughhiogjb")
---> 30         for i in outer_most_point.find('ul'):
31
32         # Job Title:

Can anybosy help me with that please.!

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Can you check now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the website is using http3 protocol.
I was able to make it work by adding needed headers and using this library : https://pypi.org/project/http3/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import http3
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

skill = 'data analyst'
place = 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',

params = {
    'q': skill,
    'l': place,
    'from': 'searchOnHP',
    'vjk': 'e32b640bd3363a4d',
}



for page in range(3):
    response = http3.get('https://in.indeed.com/jobs', params=params, headers=headers)
    html = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    print(response.status_code)
    outer_most_point=soup.find('div',attrs={'id': 'mosaic-provider-jobcards'})
```

NB : You probably want to be careful not to make to much requests and be blocked fast (be presented with captcha or such)

Comment: Are you able to access anything by class name, or id, cause I'm not able to access, previously I've build a project on stack overflow and its working fine. I don't understand for indeed and linkdin jobs I'm not able to access anything.